# lyx bibtex problem

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to get citations rendered like this (Munir, 2004). But there is no comma after rendered (Munir 2004).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the documentation](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/natbib2.pdf) for `natbib` (p. 11), maybe try adding the command `\setcitestyle{aysep={,}}`